# rest api Flask 404 for Post request

Tags: python, json, flask

I am very new to Flask and it's my first app and first question in stackoverflow(Sorry if I did something wrong). Trying to build a rest api service. When I am trying to make a post request, I always catch 404.

Also, I suppose, that I parse data incorrectly.

Below is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort, fields, marshal_with
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.app = app


class CourierModel(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    regions = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Integer), nullable=False)
    hours = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Courier: id - {self._id}, type - {self._type}'


# db.create_all()

put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
put_args.add_argument('data', action='append', type=dict)
put_args.add_argument('courier_id', type=int)
put_args.add_argument('courier_type', type=str)
put_args.add_argument('regions', type=list)
put_args.add_argument('working_hours', type=list)

patch_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
patch_args.add_argument('courier_type', type=str)
patch_args.add_argument('regions', type=list)
patch_args.add_argument('working_hors', type=list)


class Courier(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = put_args.parse_args()
        valid = []
        invalid = []
        for arg in args['data']:
            if arg['courier_type'] is None:
                invalid.append(arg['courier_id'])
            elif arg['regions'] is None or len(arg['regions']) == 0:
                invalid.append(arg['courier_id'])
            elif arg['working_hours'] is None and len(arg['working_hours']) == 0:
                invalid.append(arg['courier_id'])
            else:
                valid.append(arg['courier_id'])
                courier = CourierModel(id=arg['courier_id'],
                                       type=arg['courier_type'],
                                       regions=arg['regions'],
                                       hours=arg['working_hours'])
                db.session.add(courier)

        if len(invalid):
            return {'validation_error': {'couriers': [{'id': x} for x in invalid]}}, 400
        else:
            db.session.commit()
            return {'couriers': [{'id': x} for x in valid]}, 201

    def patch(self, courier_id):
        args = patch_args.parse_args()
        result = CourierModel.query.filter_by(id=courier_id).first()

        if args['courier_type']:
            result.type = args['courier_type']
        elif args['courier_type'] is None or args['courier_type'] == '':
            abort(400)
        if args['regions'] and len(args['regions']) > 0:
            result.regions = args['regions']
        elif args['regions'] is None and len(args['regions']) == 0:
            abort(400)
        if args['working_hours'] and len(args['working_hours']) > 0:
            result.hours = args['working_hours']
        elif args['working_hours'] is None and len(args['working_hours']) == 0:
            abort(400)

        db.session.commit()

        return {}


api.add_resource(Courier, '/couriers/<int:courier_id>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Below is my test.py, where I sending requests
test.py:

```
import requests as req

BASE = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'

resource = req.post(BASE + 'couriers/', {"data": [{"courier_id": 1, "courier_type": "foot", "regions": [1, 12, 22], "working_hours": ["11:35-14:05", "09:00-11:00"]}]})
print(resource)
```

Comment: What does the service you wrote do in returning a 404 for a POST request?

Comment: Your URL has to have the form `'/couriers/<int:courier_id>'`; you post `'/couriers/'`. Flask cannot find that, add the courier_id to the URL.

Comment: @menno-hölscher, thanks. But now I catch 400. Could you give some advices about my parsing arguments

Comment: Time for debugging. From the documentation it seems that `reqparse()` returns 400s and you do too. Start here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#when-in-doubt-run-manually However this is a completely different question. And also note that SO is not a tutoring site.